# Confirm Element and go to next tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I got some List with different Elements and every Element had it's one delete button. I want to delete a certain Element, so at first i need to confirm the Element (the Element contains: Test 1, Test2) and subsequently delete the Element

```
<div class="html-replace-container">
<form id="new_supplier_assignment" class="new_supplier_assignment" action="/supplier_assignments" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<h3 class="supplier-assignment-header progress-active">
<a href="/products/685">Test 1</a>

  -
<a href="/companies/13">Test 2</a>
</h3>
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-replace-html-container="true" data-confirm="Sind Sie sich sicher?" style="float: right" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/supplier_assignments/122?owner=Customer">Löschen</a>
```

I've got this so fare :

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=//*[@id='new_supplier_assignment']/..//*[contains(text(), 'Test 1')]/../*[contains(text(), 'Test 2')]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I want to go to `<a class="btn btn-danger ...>` and click. 
I can not use count() or indexof().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find  a `h3` which first `a` is `Test 1` and second `a` is `Test 2`, then use `following-sibling::a` to get the delete button

xpath: `//h3[a[1][text()="Test 1"] and a[2][text()="Test 2"]]/following-sibling::a`

In case you don't care which `a` is `Test 1`, it maybe the first or second `a`, If so, remove the index `[1] and [2]` , try below xpath: 
`//h3[a[text()="Test 1"] and a[text()="Test 2"]]/following-sibling::a`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text as a locator:

```
driver.findelement(by.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'YOUR TEXT')]")).click()
```

The different between the buttons is the text 'Test 1' 'Test 2' so you can locate the element and delete it by his text.

Comment: I won't work. I don't wont to click on Test 1 or Test 2. I need to confirme Test 1 and Test 2. If there are identicaly with my search value I can delete them otherwise don't